# Attempting to hydrate existing `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js` markup error in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, appwrite

I am currently working on a simple app to store workout routines in Nuxt 3 and Appwrite. The link to the source code is [here](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/workout-buddy).

Whenever I try to navigate to the `/login` or `/signup` route by clicking the links in the navbar, on the first click the page source is not re-rendered (i.e. I keep seeing the same text `Landing Page`, and on refreshing the route, I get the 500 server error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Tf1.png)

The console logs the following warnings, but I have no idea how to correct them or why are they originating.
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsRRK.png)

Any help as to why this hydration error is generating would be really helpful!

PS:

1. Most probably the error should be originating from either the `/pages/signup.vue`,
   `/pages/login.vue` or `/components/navbar.vue`.
2. I am using Appwrite to manage the back-end of the web app, and the instructions to setup the same can be found in the README.md. (Though I don't think the error I am facing is related to the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a property of `null` type. That's why you are getting the error.

```
 <div v-if="error.show" class="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
```

In the above line, you are trying to access `error.show` but from the global store, the returned `error` value is `null` type.So you are trying to access the `show` property on a `null` type and thus getting the error.

There are many solutions to handle this. Either, you can just check it in the computed property, or you can use simply add optional chaining like this

```
 <div v-if="error?.show" class="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
```